# Extract information using classified raster in R

Tags: r, class, extract, raster, r-sp

I have a classified raster image with 12 classes and would like to use it to extract information form another raster. I want to extract information from each class in the classified raster. How do I do this please?

```
library(raster)
R1 <- raster(nrows=108, ncols=21, xmn=-19, xmx=19,ymn=2, xmx=29)
###Let's assume the classified raster is D1, I'll like to use the classes of D1 within the boundaries of R1 to extract classified information form R1. 
RD1<-extract(R1, D1)  ### where D1 is a raster with classes
```

The classified image is available at the link below:
    [Koppen-Geiger climate classes](http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/data/Koeppen-Geiger-GIS.zip)

Comment: In case, you want to extract information from a raster based on another raster (as mentioned in your question) you can use `mask` instead of `extract`.

Comment: hi @rar. the issue I have is the masking is being done generally rather than per category. If there was a way to mask by class, it should work. How do I do this, please?

Comment: One way is that you can make mask for individual classes. E.g. `m1<-D1`, `m1[!m1==1]<-NA` will create mask `m1` for class 1. And so you can make masks for each class. You can also make mask for selected classes. E.g. `m<-D1`,`m1[m1>5]<-NA` will create mask for classes 1 to 5.

Comment: Thanks@rar. Tim's approach was more direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Joke O: It sounds like you're looking for the `zonal` function in the `raster` package. Using this function, you can specify what information you want to extract for each class (e.g. sum, min, mean, max, etc.).

See the `raster` package documentation:

```
zonal((x, z, fun='mean', digits=0, na.rm=TRUE, ...))
```

where x is the raster object, and y is the classified raster with 12 classes.